# How to use a list of String instead of Resource Array in android

Tags: android, android-adapter

I am using the following line of code currently and it works fine. I have an array called somearray declared under strings.xml

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_teh = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(AttendActivity.this, R.array.somearray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

However, I now wish to use `List<String>` instead of R.array.somearray. Basically, I am now getting a List from an API call which needs to be populated to the adapter_teh instead of the hardcoded array in Strings.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ArrayAdapter<String>` and pass your `List<String>` to adapter constructor, try below code

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_teh = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AttendActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, yourArrayList);
```

Hope this help you and solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

from resources

```
String[] yourStringArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.stringarray);
```

using String class

```
String[] yourStringArray = new String[]{"A1","A3","A4","A6","A7","A8"};
```

Common Adapter

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(AttendActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,yourStringArray);
```

Comment: yes, edited, that should work, you just need to dynamically populate the string array now.